# Search Error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: search, error

I am working with a SharePoint 2013 on premise environment however I have issues. That started randomly occurring yesterday.

When I navigate to search I am seeing the error:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I get a correlation ID however when looking this up in the logs it returns nothing. A few high and medium level but nothing that stands out.

I have tried deleting the service application and recreating it, I have also emptied out the SharePoint cache re-indexed the entire site and run a full crawl.

The search service account has Full Control over the User Profile Service. It also has read access to term store on the managed metadata service.

[image: Error]

I am however finding a critical error in the event viewer that corresponds to search this is showing:

> The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CustomDictionaryDeploymentJobDefinition (ID 8501702e-278a-4001-b72c-46e3e8a5c1ce) threw an exception. More information is included below.
>
> Failed to run flow Microsoft.CustomDictionaryDeployment. Correlation Id: 88af989d-41fc-3087-f766-9cd44f0af4af.

Again when I lookup this correlation id in the logs I just get the same error back.

Any help please

Comment: I am getting same error on deploying solution in SharePoint 2016. Any Common Solution ? >> http://bit.ly/2g2bRte